# Why is this JavasScript validation not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, submit

I have a form with text input and button.

There is a bit of JavaScript to validate whether the username is null or not. If it is null it will show a validation message, otherwise will submit the form.

Problem is the onclick even does not fire in Firefox. It works in every other browser.

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong? Thanks a lot.

HTML:

    `<form name="myForm" action="TestController">
    <input type="text" width="50" name="username" />
    <button onclick="submitForm()">Go</button>
    <span class="errSpan"></span>
    </form>`

JavaScript:

```
(function(NAMESPACE){

NAMESPACE.submitForm = function(){
    console.log('invoked');
    window.event.preventDefault();
  console.log(window.myForm.username.value);

  if(window.myForm.username.value === "")
    document.getElementsByClassName('errSpan')[0].innerHTML = 'cannot be null';
  else {
    document.myForm.submit();
  }
}
})(window);
```

[Here is link to JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9stmsam7/14/)

Comment: Any solutions yet? None of the given answers work. Though it works fine on Chromium based browsers (Edge and Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

In firefox window.event is undefined, and your code fail with error.

Use addEventListener to add submit event for form, and remove the onclick statement from button.

```
window.myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //any code what you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should pass the event to the `submitForm()` method.

```
onclick="submitForm(event)"
```

then use that event argument to call `preventDefault`

```
NAMESPACE.submitForm = function(e){
    console.log('invoked');
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(window.myForm.username.value);
    ...
}
```

Or use `onsubmit` method to call your submit function and stop event propogration i.e. submitting the form.